# -m command line flag not working when specifying full path to Python script

Tags: python, command-line

So I have a python script which I can call like this (if in the same directory):

```
python -m fooscriptdirectory
```

It works just fine, it gives me the output.

But if I try to run this from somewhere else with a full path in the terminal like so:

```
python -m /home/user/public_html/fooscriptdirectory
```

I get: `No module named /home/user/public_html/fooscriptdirectory`

Why is that? It is exactly the same command right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: That is not how the `-m` option works: it requires a *module* name (that is on the PYTHONPATH, that is, that normally can be imported by Python), possibly including dotted submodules. It does *not* work with providing a path.

Comment: Ensure that `fooscriptdirectory` is in your PYTHONPATH, then just use it from anywhere with `python -m fooscriptdirectory`.

Comment: Thanks guys, was able to fix it by adding it to the PYTHONPATH :)